# How to update a website deployed on heroku?

Tags: heroku

I created a [website](https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com/) that I deployed on heroku. I have made some changes there and am looking to update my website to reflect these changes. To do this, I ran the following commands:

```
git status 
git init
git status
git remote -v

git add .
git commit -m"The file"
 git push heroku masterbranch
```

I want to clarify that the `masterbranch` branch is a branch that has been created. The base `branch` of my website is `master` not `masterbranch`. The reason why, I created a new branch is that when I ran the command: `git push heroku master` I was getting the error:error: **failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/gkwhelps.git'**  But I don't think that is the reason why my deployed site does not is not up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Git itself.  See the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), which notes that:

> Heroku only deploys code that you push to the `master` or `main` branches of the remote. Pushing code to another branch of the heroku remote has no effect.

You mention:

> when I ran the command: `git push heroku master` I was getting the error: `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/gkwhelps.git'`

When you push to the main or master branch, Heroku will:

1. read your code;
2. attempt to *build* your code based on what it read in step 1;
3. attempt to *deploy* your build from step 3.

Any of these three steps can have errors.  If they do have errors, Heroku uses Git to *relay these errors to you* and then tells Git to produce the above error message.  So Git says that your push failed, but that's because *Heroku told Git to fail it*.  You cannot fix this problem by creating another branch.  You must address the problems that occurred in steps 1, 2, and/or 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you first push your code on Github and from Github do deploy, you shoud do:

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m 'changes'
git push
```

After that you should connect Heroku with Github and do deploy from that branch from Github.